# Appengine's Indexing order, cursors, and aggregation

Tags: google-app-engine, cursor, aggregation, datastore

I need to do some continuous aggregation on a data set.  I am using app engines High Replication Datastore.

Lets say we have a simple object with a property that holds a string of the date when it's created. There's other fields associated with the object but it's not important in this example.

Lets say I create and store some objects. Below is the date associated with each object. Each object is stored in the order below. These objects will be created in separate transactions.

```
Obj1: 2012-11-11
Obj2: 2012-11-11
Obj3: 2012-11-12
Obj4: 2012-11-13
Obj5: 2012-11-14
```

The idea is to use a cursor to continually check for new indexed objects. Aggregation on the new indexed entities will be performed.

Here are the questions I have:

1)  Are objects indexed in order? As in is it possible for Obj4 to be indexed before Obj 1,2, and 3? This will be a issue if i use a ORDER BY query and a cursor to continue searching. Some entities will not be found if there is a delay in indexing.

2) If no ORDER BY is specified, what order are entities returned in a query?

3) How would I go about checking for new indexed entities? As in, grab all entities, storing the cursor, then later on checking if any new entities were indexed since the last query?

Little less important, but food for thought

4) Are all fields indexed together? As in, if I have a date property, and lets say a name property, will both properties appear to be indexed at the same time for a given object?

5) If multiple entities are written in the same transaction, are all entities in the transaction indexed at the same time?

6) If all entities belong to the same entity group, are all entities indexed at the same time?

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: if you add new items etc the cursor becomes irrelevant (outdated). So I don't think you can use it as you note.

Comment: Under some scenarios, yes. However, I will not be modifying data before the cursor so the cursor should still be valid. It's important to get my query right so new indexes will always be after the cursor.

Please read "Cursors and Data Updates" if interested.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Cursors_and_Data_Updates

Comment: Ah, just found this in the documentation to

Also found this on cursors
New App Engine releases may change internal implementation details, invalidating cursors that depend on them. If an application attempts to use a cursor that is no longer valid, the Datastore raises a BadRequestError exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All entities have default indexes for every property. If you use `ORDER BY someProperty` then you will get entities ordered by values of that property. You are correct on index building: queries use indexes and indexes are built asynchronously, meaning that it's possible that query will not find an entity immediately after it was added.
2. `ORDER BY` defaults to `ASC`, i.e. ascending order.
3. Add a `created` timestamp to you entity then order by it and repeat the cursor. See [Cursors and Data Updates](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Cursors_and_Data_Updates).
4. Indexes are built after `put()` operation returns. They are also built in parallel. Meaning that when you query some indexes may be build, some not. See [Life of a Datastore Write](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write). Note that if you want to force *"apply"* on an entity you can issue a `get()` after `put()`, which will force the changes to be applied (= indexes written).
5. and 6. All entities touched in the same transaction must be in the same entity group (=have common parent). [Transaction isolation docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation) state that transactions can be unapplied, meaning that query after `put()` will not find new entities. Again, you can force entity to be applied via a read or ancestor query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding #2, What property is used if no ORDER BY is used? Is it key values? Or does it return entities in the order they are indexed?

For #3, I am planning not to re-run the cursor. As in, run a query, store the cursor, and repeat.  As you said it's possible to miss entities if there is a delay in indexing, this will be a problem for me...

Regarding 5 & 6 you can have multiple entity groups in a single transaction! https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Cross_Group_Transactions I was curious if all indexes appeared at the same time.

Comment: I was curious if all indexes appeared at the same time a transaction is applied that is

Comment: If no ORDER BY is used entities are returned in key order (you can see that in GAE Admin - Data Viewer).

Comment: After apply phase is done all indexes are done, meaning you see them all. The problem is you can not know when apply phase is done. However you can force apply phase to finish by executing read or ancestor query after put.

Comment: Ah, just found this in the documentation. 

Ordering of query results is undefined when no sort order is specified. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Queries_on_Keys

Comment: Regarding #1, I know entities won't appear in the index immediately. For me it's important that when they get indexed, they are indexed in the order they are persisted. The following link specifies that data is split into tablets, and then indexed in parallel. Parallel workers can fail. So this means there is no guarantee that your data is indexed in order, meaning queries can be missing data. developers.google.com/appengine/articles/index_building Unless there is a way to grab the latest indexed entities by using a cursor, then there is no way my idea to be 100% reliable

Comment: I guess the best way to go about it is using ancestor queries and create multiple entity groups like you said. Thanks for your time.